# create app with menu at the bottom (like many iphone apps), how to organize activity / fragments

Tags: android, android-activity, controller, fragment

I want to create a app with a menu at the bottom of the screen. This menu should be visible any time the app is started.
Im working with fragments, so the menu is one fragment.

So I have only one Activity as controller which loads different fragments above the menu fragment.
Because I want to create clean code, i dont know how to solve the problem that the Activity class is too big.

In other words, i want to create different controller within the same activity. How to do that?
Is there another approach to solve this issue?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html (see "Don't use bottom tab bars")

Comment: i know that, but this is not the question!
It is a case study!

Comment: Split Action Bar menus are part of the Android design guide.  He is not talking about tabs but a menu.  See http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the [split action bar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) This allows you to put the Actions and overflow menu on the bottom of the screen.  I believe you can use [Action Bar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) for backwards compatibility to older versions of Android.  See their site for detail.

Another possibility is to look into using fragments with the [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) .  Here is a library that works with compatability as well [ViewPageIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) .  Here is a [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) , like I indicated in my comment I got this working with the tabs showing at the bottom and the pages above.

Comment: That first link goes to the official Android design page, you shouldn't try to use a Fragment since an official method for putting a menu at the screen bottom exists.

Comment: A split action bar does not mean that there is always something at the bottom of the screen. It will only appear at the bottom of the screen for smaller-sized screens in portrait orientation. I agree that this is the closest recommended approach that relates to the OP's request. However, it is not a precise match. Moreover, iOS developers coming to Android have a tendency to refer to what we would consider bottom tabs as a "menu" -- I am uncertain whether that is due to iOS's terms or what.

Comment: I see, I never owned an iOS device so I didn't realize that.  I did a proof of concept app using the Viewpager and getting the tabs to work from the bottom of the screen (flipping the pages above the tabs.  The reason to do this is people's thumbs find it easier to navigate at the bottom of the device.  Especially these large phones being made today.

Comment: You are welcome to your opinion. For countervailing expert opinion, see http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/08/tips-for-android-tabs.html, in addition to the official design guidelines that I cited in my comment on the question.

Comment: I agree, however people with small hands have trouble with menus at the top of a phone screen.